# vim looks different when i launch it via the terminal

Tags: neovim, colorscheme

I'm using NVIM 0.2.2. When I launch it from the terminal, the color scheme of the terminal affects it's look. And when I launch it from the search menu, it works just fine[image]

What makes it behaves that way? and how to solve it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminal colours affect any colours in the 16 or 256 colour palette. Most terminal emulators have a pretty standard 256 colour palette, but customize the bottom 16 colors to set the terminal colour scheme. Many vim colourschemes use these 16 colours, so will look very different depending on the terminal colour scheme. There are multiple methods to debug and fix this.

A good first step might be to work out how the 'launch from the search menu' and 'open in the terminal' methods of running neovim differ. Are they different terminals? etc.

- if using a custom vim colorscheme, follow the instructions on that. eg. a solarized colorscheme might ask you to set the terminal 16 colors to the solarized colours.
- if you can't or don't want to change the terminal colour scheme, look for a true colour (if your terminal supports it) or a 256 colour colorscheme for vim. this will give a standard look regardless of the terminal colour scheme.
- be careful reading older posts that talk about playing with vim options like `t_Co` and friends; in newer vim versions and neovim these are *rarely* needed and mostly works out of the box. This can be a common gotcha. ;)